# c# Использование прокси в WebBrowser

Tags: c#, proxy, webbrowser, gecko

Использую Gecko браузер (от Mozill'ы).

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Skybound.Gecko;

namespace shit_browser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Xpcom.Initialize(@"C:\XPCOM");

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.ru", 0, "", null, "");
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно использовать прокси. Авторизовываться через логин&пароль. Как такое реализовать?